# Apache RewriteRule to filesystem

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to get my very simple rewrite rule working.
I am trying to rewrite to a filesystem.

Here is my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) /var/www/sonarApps/main/com.sonar6.api/account/master/web
```

This will not work. It looks like it is always trying to load it from the apache web root, so

```
/apache/web/root/var/www/sonarApps/main/com.sonar6.api/account/master/web
```

This is my log

```
10.54.1.188 - - [06/Jun/2013:09:26:14 +0500] [...][rid#2b1b8b4f6ed0/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /zef-test/master/api/index.php
10.54.1.188 - - [06/Jun/2013:09:26:14 +0500] [...][rid#2b1b8b4f6ed0/initial] (1) pass through /zef-test/master/api/index.php
10.54.1.188 - - [06/Jun/2013:09:26:14 +0500] [...][rid#2b1b8b4f6ed0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/sonarRoot/zef-test/master/api/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/sonarRoot/zef-test/master/api/index.php -> index.php
10.54.1.188 - - [06/Jun/2013:09:26:14 +0500] [...][rid#2b1b8b4f6ed0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/sonarRoot/zef-test/master/api/] applying pattern '^(.*)' to uri 'index.php'
10.54.1.188 - - [06/Jun/2013:09:26:14 +0500] [...][rid#2b1b8b4f6ed0/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/sonarRoot/zef-test/master/api/] rewrite 'index.php' -> '/var/www/sonarApps/main/com.sonar6.api/account/master/web'
10.54.1.188 - - [06/Jun/2013:09:26:14 +0500] [...][rid#2b1b8b4f6ed0/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/sonarRoot/zef-test/master/api/] internal redirect with /var/www/sonarApps/main/com.sonar6.api/account/master/web [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
10.54.1.188 - - [06/Jun/2013:09:26:14 +0500] [...][rid#2b1b8b502f10/initial/redir#1] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /var/www/sonarApps/main/com.sonar6.api/account/master/web
10.54.1.188 - - [06/Jun/2013:09:26:14 +0500] [...][rid#2b1b8b502f10/initial/redir#1] (1) pass through /var/www/sonarApps/main/com.sonar6.api/account/master/web
10.54.1.188 - - [06/Jun/2013:09:26:14 +0500] [...][rid#2b1b8b4faef0/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /favicon.ico
10.54.1.188 - - [06/Jun/2013:09:26:14 +0500] [...][rid#2b1b8b4faef0/initial] (1) pass through /favicon.ico
```

Reading the apache mod_rewrite doc

```
A full filesystem path to a resource
RewriteRule ^/games /usr/local/games/web
This maps a request to an arbitrary location on your filesystem, much like the Alias directive.
```

This doesn't seem to be working in my case.
Any ideas?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filesystem rewrite rules is not supported in per directory rules, from 
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

```
file-system path
Designates the location on the file-system of the resource to be delivered to the client. Substitutions are only treated as a file-system path when the rule is configured in server (virtualhost) context and the first component of the path in the substitution is exists in the file-system
```

Answer (score 0):

This is normal: you specify to replace the path with the same value. This behaviour is therefore expected.

You need to append the path you have captured into the substituion. What is more, here your `^` is not needed:

```
RewriteRule (.*) /var/www/sonarApps/main/com.sonar6.api/account/master/web/$1
```

Comment: Thx fge but this is still not working.
The log is the same...
Any other ideas?

Comment: Uh yeah, I know why now. This form of rewrite rule will rewrite the URL. I don't remember offhand how to use it to go to the filesystem... But how come you redirect everything? Isn't your DocumentRoot set?

Comment: Here it was for the example. I wanted to see the redirect occurring.
DocumentRoot is set, but for this particular url (pointing to a subfolder of my document root) I want it to be redirected to another folder.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite rule should be in server (VirtualHost) context.

Thus your configuration should look like

```
<VirtualHost *> 
...
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) /var/www/sonarApps/main/com.sonar6.api/account/master/web$1
</VirtualHost>
```

Or if you need it inside e.g. Location, you may need to define alias

```
<VirtualHost *> 

Alias "/masterweb" "/var/www/sonarApps/main/com.sonar6.api/account/master/web"
...
<Location / >
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) /masterweb$1
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

[mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) Substitutions are only treated as a file-system path when the rule is configured in server (virtualhost) context and the first component of the path in the substitution exists in the file-system.